# React-Native PDF Annotation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, pdf, react-hooks, react-redux

"I have tried drawing over pdf but I can't implement it.
I had stuck in this task can you please share any references or any way to implement this."

- How to draw over PDF / Also highlight any text.

1. Draw over Existing PDF in react native. and download it.
2. Choose PDF from our Devices.

Comment: I believe you are looking for this: https://pdfjs.express/documentation/react

Just google "pdfjs react native annotation" and you will find several resutls

Comment: @AmitKhanna Yes, I had referred it, but my requirement is to do listed things in my app. not used any kind of browser support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple library options available for pdf annotation.

- pdftron-react-native : https://github.com/PDFTron/pdftron-react-native (I have used this and it worked for me fine. Check your requirements are available or not.)
- react-pdf-annotations : https://github.com/agentcooper/react-pdf-highlighter
- https://pspdfkit.com/pdf-sdk/react-native/annotations/
- react-native-pdf : https://github.com/wonday/react-native-pdf

Comment: I had tried all the things 
(1) React-native-pdf :
         -- it's only used for a PDF view.
(2)pdf Tron-react-native:
        -- i tried to implement this but getting error for offline mode in android and for  IOS ,when installing a pods it's too wait for installing and also not installed successfully.

Comment: Not done yet.
-- Need some help.

Comment: pod install error can be because of several reasons. Kindly check you are following all the steps as per doc. version requirements as well.

Comment: it's not getting me an error but it's a long-time install.

```Installing PDFNet (3.0.2-beta.104)```

Stuck at this line.

Comment: Make sure you have unrestricted internet access

Comment: ```https://pspdfkit.com/pdf-sdk/react-native/annotations/```
- It Works me fine right now. but it's paid library so I can't afford it.